# org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.IllegalMappingException: Non-existent mapping property

Tags: grails-orm, grails-4

```
2019-08-13 22:56:45.466 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. 
Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. 
Message: Error creating bean with name   
'authenticationProcessingFilterDeregistrationBean': Cannot resolve 
reference to bean 'authenticationProcessingFilter' while setting bean 
property 'filter'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'authenticationProcessingFilter': Cannot resolve 
reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 
'authenticationManager'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to 
bean 'daoAuthenticationProvider' while setting constructor argument 
with key [0]; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'daoAuthenticationProvider': Cannot resolve reference to 
bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 
'userDetailsService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through method 'setTargetDatastore' parameter 0; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor 
threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.IllegalMappingException: Non-existent mapping property [superior] specified for property [subordinadas] in class [motivacao.Estrategia]
```

I am getting an above error in grails 4.

This code working fine in grails 2.5.6.

```
class Deeh extends Iniciativa {

    SimNao estaAtiva

    static constraints = {
        instalacao      (blank: false)
        organizacao     (blank: false)
        superior        (nullable: true)
        risco           (nullable: true)
        recompensa      (nullable: true)
        objetivo        (nullable: true)
        estaAtiva       (nullable: true)
        resumo          (nullable: true, unique:'instalacao', maxSize: 120)
        detalhe         (nullable: true, maxSize: 500, widget: 'textarea')
        instalacao              (blank: false)
        meta                    (nullable: true)
        objetivo                (nullable: true)
        estrategia              (nullable: true)
        tatica                  (nullable: true)
        organizacao             (blank: false)
        naturezaIniciativa      (blank: false)
        tipoImpacto             (nullable: true)
        tipoUrgencia            (nullable: true)
        prioridade              (nullable: true, length:2, maxSize:2)
        prioridadeCalculada     (editable:false, nullable: true, length:2, maxSize:2)
        nivelAtuacao            (blank: false)
        riscos                  (nullable: true)
        //        estado                  (blank: false)
        valorCentral            (nullable: true)
        responsavel             (nullable: true)
        previsaoDeInicio        (nullable: true)
        previsaoDeConclusao     (nullable: true)
        dataDeInicio            (nullable: true)
        dataDeConclusao         (nullable: true)
        subtitulo               (nullable: true, maxSize:90)
        custoGlobal             (nullable: true)
        nivelH                  (nullable: true)
        superior                (nullable: true)
        previsaoDeInicio        (nullable: true)
        previsaoDeConclusao     (nullable: true)
        dataDeInicio            (nullable: true)
        dataDeConclusao         (nullable: true)
        gestor                  (nullable: true)
        patrocinador            (nullable: true)
        subordinados             (nullable: true)
        acoes                   (nullable: true)
        documentos              (nullable: true)

        percConclusaoCalc (nullable: true)
        percConclusaoInfo (nullable: true)

    }


    Estrategia superior

    Meta     meta
    Objetivo objetivo
    Risco    risco
    RecompensaPotencial recompensa

    static belongsTo = [Meta, Objetivo, Risco, Estrategia, Regra,
                        Risco, RecompensaPotencial]

    Collection subordinadas, iniciativas, taticas, politicas
    static hasMany = [subordinadas: Estrategia, iniciativas: Iniciativa,
                      taticas: Tatica, politicas: Politica]


    static mappedBy = [objetivo:'estrategias',
                       iniciativas:'estrategia',
                       taticas:'estrategias',
                       subordinadas: 'superior']


    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
        estaAtiva          (column: 'estaAtivo', type:SimNaoType)
        superior           (column: 'superior')
        sort               (dataInclusao:'desc', dataAlteracao:'desc' )
    }

    def afterInsert = {
        super.afterInsert.run()
    }

    def afterUpdate = {
        super.afterUpdate.run()
    }

    def beforeInsert = {
        super.beforeInsert.run()
    }

    def beforeUpdate = {
        super.beforeUpdate.run()
    }

    def afterDelete = {
        // super.delete()
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: have you found a solution yet?